# How to enable YCM for MacVim only (while keep it disabled for terminal Vim)

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I've been using Vim for a while but still get confused by configuration. I want to config my Vim in such a way that YCM (YouCompleteMe, an auto-complete plugin) *only* gets loaded if running in **GUI mode** (e.g. MacVim), while if **terminal Vim** (maybe misnomer, I mean text-based Vim launched from command line) runs, YCM won't be loaded.

This question actually can be generalized to "How to selectively load plugins depending on running mode?". I though it must has been considered elsewhere, but Google gets me little useful information.

Comment: Without getting into your general question, YCM will probably work just as well in MacVim CLI executable (`$ mvim -v`) as it would in the GUI. Like most plugins.

Comment: How have you installed the plugin? (Are you using plugin manager or did you install it manually?)

Comment: @FDinoff I'm currently using Vundle.

Comment: @bl4ck5un do what @Laser suggested and put the `Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` command in the `has("gui_running")` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if has("gui_running")
    ... enable gui stuff here
else
    ... enable terminal stuff here
endif
```

(see `h: feature-list`)

Comment: As @FDinoff pointed out, putting `Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` in the `has("gui_running")` solved the problem.

Comment: Yes - I took a shortcut: instead of asking you how you installed the plugin (and prepare a long and well-thought answer), I just went for your "more general" question and gave a short answer :)

Comment: Sure thing. I wrote that down just for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Put your GUI-only configuration in the file .gvimrc.

Console Vim sources .vimrc when it starts. GUI Vim sources .vimrc and then .gvimrc, so settings in .gvimrc can override settings in .vimrc. For more information, see [`:help gui-start`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html).